# Get value of list item

Tags: javascript, html, list

I have a list like so:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="index.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="procedures.php">Procedures</a></li>
        <li><a href="consultation.php">Consultations</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="library.php">3D Library</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to use Javascript to get value of the first `<li>` and alert it out...like so:

```
alert(document.getElementById('navigation').options[1]);
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The `.options` property is for `select` elements.

You should use `.children[0]` and then `.textContent` or `.innerText` for older IE.

---

Start by defining a variable at the top of your application for browser support:

```
var text = "textContent" in document ? "textContent" : "innerText";
```

---

Then use it like this:

```
alert(document.getElementById('navigation').children[1][text]);
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/4ec4R/